# Minting new position on Uniswap V3 using hardhat

Tags: ethers.js, uniswap, typescript, uniswapv3

So basically I am trying to mint a position in a pool created by me.

To create and initialise the pool:

```
  const factory = await ethers.getContractAt("UniswapV3Factory", factoryAddress)
  
  let poolAddress = await factory.getPool("0x40a42Baf86Fc821f972Ad2aC878729063CeEF403", "0x4bf010f1b9beDA5450a8dD702ED602A104ff65EE", 500);

  const pool = await ethers.getContractAt("UniswapV3Pool", poolAddress);
  try{
    await pool.initialize(BigNumber.from(2).pow(96));
  } catch(exception){
    console.log("Pool already initialized");
  }
```

Then to try to had liquidity I tried this:

```
  let signer = await ethers.getSigner("0xf39Fd6e51aad88F6F4ce6aB8827279cffFb92266");

  await pool.connect(signer).mint(signer.address,-20,20,10000000,[]);
```

I realise it is missing the transfer of the tokens (which is suposed to come in a callback of the mint function) but I don't know how to implement it! Any ideas?

Or is this simply the wrong approach and there is a better on?

Comment: This would be much easier to do with [Foundry](https://getfoundry.sh/).

Answer (score 0):

You may need to create a position in the pool.

Checkout: https://docs.uniswap.org/sdk/guides/liquidity/minting

Comment: Thats what I am trying to do! From my understanding the sdk actually doesnt allow u interact with the blockchain, its just to simulate I believe